# $R$ semisimple ring and $M$ finitely generated $R$-mod implies that $End_R(M)$ is semisimple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, semi-simple-rings

> Let $R$ be a semisimple ring and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-mod. Show that $End_R(M)$ is semisimple.

I was thinking of somehow showing that I can get an isomorphism between $R$ and $End_R(M)$ since I know there is an injection to the endomorphisms of $M$ from $R$, and maybe using the property of $M$ being finitely generated, but I'm not sure if this is the direction to take.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The endomorphism ring of any finitely generated semisimple $R$-module is semisimple.
Every module over a semisimple ring is a semisimple module.

The module $M$ can be written as $N_1^{a_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus N_k^{a_k}$
where the $N_i$ are pairwise non-isomorphic simple modules. The endormophism
ring of $M$ will be the direct product of those of the $N_1^{a_i}$ which are matrix
rings over skew fields.

Comment: First, what does the super script denote on the simple modules. Second, I don't quite understand the last sentence. The ring of endomorphisms will be a direct product of the $N_i^{a_i}$, and the $N_i^{a_i}$ are matrix rings?

Comment: $N^a$ is the Cartesian product of $N$ with itself $a$ times, "Those of" means "the endomorphism rings of"

Comment: @user439126 If you haven‘t seen it, you should check out the Artin–Wedderburn theorem.